# MonoTouch Core-Plot Binding

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, plot, core-plot

I have trouble with using the Core-Plot library in MonoTouch. I use [this](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/) as a starting point for my MonoTouch binding. For me it seems the binding isn't finished.

I miss classes like CPXYGraph and CPGraphHostingView... Probably I don't need the CPXYGraph class, but how do I create an instance of CPGraph?

Does anyone succesfully used Core-Plot in MonoTouch and/or have an example?

Wich other solutions for plotting in MonoTouch would you recommend? (I can't use the google chart api, because it isn't guaranted that an Internet connection is available)

**Edit:**

Here is some example code I have problems with:

```
CPTheme theme = CPTheme.ThemeNamed("Plain Black"); // Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
CPGraph graph = (CPGraph)theme.NewGraph();
```

I use the *Core Plot Alpha Release 0.2.2* version and link with:

```
-gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lCorePlot -force_load "${ProjectDir}/libCorePlot.a" -ObjC"
```

Comment: What makes you think its incomplete?  That binding is complete and people are using it.

Comment: I miss classes like CPXYGraph. Many of the Core-Plot tutorials and the Core-Plot documentation (for ObjectiveC) use it. Is it possible that I use the wrong version of Core-Plot?

Comment: If there are missing classes, you should just extend the binding.

Comment: I added some details... Do you now a better place for asking questions about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wait for the second alpha of MonoTouch 4.0, you will be able to run the new sample that I added to the build which has a full working setup and I added various plot types that were missing.